# Show that $\inf_{y\in A} \|x-y\| = \inf_{\nu \in \mathcal{M}(A)} \|x - \mathbb{E}_\nu Y\|$

Tags: probability-theory, optimization, metric-spaces

Suppose that $A \subset [0,1]^n$ is convex and $x \in [0,1]^n$. Let $\mathcal{M}(A)$ be the set of probability measures on $A$ and $Y = (Y_1,\ldots, Y_n)$ denotes a random vector distributed according to some $\nu \in \mathcal{M}(A)$, it is mentioned (without any proof) in the proof of Lemma 7.11 of [this book](https://www.hse.ru/data/2016/11/24/1113029206/Concentration%20inequalities.pdf) that $$\inf_{y\in A} \|x-y\| = \inf_{\nu \in \mathcal{M}(A)} \|x - \mathbb{E}_\nu Y\|.$$ I am not sure how such identity can be derived and why do we need the assumption on the convexity of the set $A$. Although one direction is easy, as by taking $\nu = \delta_y$ for some (or any) $y\in A$ we can obtain $\inf\limits_{\nu \in \mathcal{M}(A)} \|x - \mathbb{E}_\nu Y\| \leq \inf\limits_{y\in A} \|x-y\|.$ But this inequality does not need any convexity assumption on the set $A$. I appreciate any help on this problem!

---

A closely related problem arises in the proof of Lemma 7.10 of the aforementioned book. It is mentioned (again without any proof) that $$\inf_{y \in A} \sum_{i\colon x_i \neq y_i} 1 = \inf_{\nu \in \mathcal{M}(A)} \sum_{j=1}^n \mathbb{E}_\nu\mathbf{1}\{x_j \neq Y_j\}.$$ One direction is still easy to establish but I am really stuck on the proof of the other direction. I appreciate any help on this problem as well!

Comment: Not placing any bets on this , but expecting it to be true : so you have $A \subset [0,1]^n$ convex : therefore, it is the convex hull of its extreme points, a set we'll denote by $E$. What I believe should be true, is that $\mathcal M(A)$ (which is a convex set) actually has precisely the set $\{\delta_e : e \in E\}$ as its set of extreme points, and is therefore (Krein-Milman) the convex hull of those set of measures. Now, a function like $\|...\|$ looks convex, so it will attain its minimum on an extreme point, which is then going to be a $\delta$ measure.

Comment: I believe the first equality in the proof of lemma 7.11 follows from the fact that since $A$ is convex, $\mathbb{E}_\nu Y \in A$ for any $\nu \mathcal{M}(A)$. This wouldn't necessarily be the case if $A$ wasn't convex: think of a measure that puts half its mass on $x$ and half on $y$ in this [picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_set#/media/File:Convex_polygon_illustration2.svg). I then think that should let us conclude that $$\inf_{\nu \in \mathcal{M}(A)} \|x - \mathbb{E}_\nu Y\| = \inf\limits_{\nu = \delta_y, y\in A} \|x- \mathbb{E}_\nu Y\|. $$

Comment: @Shiva Your comment looks reasonable, so the second identity follows from a similar reasoning as well?

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer Thank you very much! But how about the second (similar) question in the proof of Lemma 7.10? Here no convexity assumption on $A$ was made...

Comment: It you are going to ask multiple questions and get picky, you might want to make the second question clear rather than make a rambling comment and expect the answerer to extract the question for you. In any case, the expectation can reach any point in the convex hull of $A$, so if $A$ is not convex it is straightforward to construct a counterexample.